# The woods following their side of the road

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

Is it correct to say:

> "They were standing ten feet or so behind the car, gazing and sniffing in the direction of **the woods following their side of the road.**"

Meaning: a long road with woods on both sides, from beginning to end.

If it's incorrect in any way, please show examples of how to fix it without changing the meaning of the phrase.

[image: woods]

Comment: Were they dogs?

Comment: Yes, the were. Lol

Answer (score 2):

Options:

The woods are on both sides.
So, either one side or the other or both. You have to specify:
**at the woods on both sides of the road**.
Or: **at the woods on the left side of the road or the right side of the road**.
Or:  **at the woods on their side of the road**.

Also, gazing and sniffing at the woods, etc.// no direction or following.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie, but maybe I should’ve been more specific with what I want to know. 

Is it correct to say the woods follow the road? 

Is it correct to say “your side of the road” if you’re referring to the side of road you are on? 

(The phrase must contain the information that the character is looking towards the woods on the side of the road they are on)

Comment: Maybe I should've change to something like this example by adding alongside: "Also, it's a really great place to run/walk, as the park has a continuous paved loop following alongside the road/shore"

Comment: It sounds odd to say that the woods 'follow' the road. Lambie has already told you that you can say _the woods on their side of the road_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, however that does not express that there are woods on the side of the road from beginning to end, which is the scenario in this case. It sounds odd to me too, which is why I'm asking, but that is question 1, question 2 is:Is it correct to say “your side of the road” if you’re referring to the side of road you are on? (The phrase must contain the information that the character is looking towards the woods on the side of the road they are on). This second question was not addressed, maybe I should put a second question.

Comment: I've found more examples: "Also, it's a really great place to run/walk, as the park has a continuous paved loop following alongside the road/shore." --- "The trail will bend to the right, following alongside the road. The trail now climbs steeply for a minute." --- "....apparent as the blue pylons following alongside the road indicated the natural gas transmission line ran directly below where the sample had been taken." --- "About a mile up the mountain, you'll start to see Staton Creek following alongside the road."

Comment: "They were gazing at the woods lining/edging their side of the road." All your examples of _following_ refer to something linear (path, line of pylons, creek). If the road passes through the middle of the woods, they are not exactly 'following' it.

Comment: @ksds The picture shows woods but it doesn't show a road with woods from one end to the other of the actual road.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you, makes sense to me now and I agree. Thank you, Lambie. I guess technically you are correct, because the picture does not show the entire road, but the portion of the road/woods that does show in the picture has woods on both sides without gaps or breaks (at least from what I've noticed it). However I do understand that the picture did not seem to help in describing what I wanted to know.

Comment: @ksds If we say: gazing at the woods along the [x] side of the road, it means all the woods you can see there. We would not specify along the entire road because you can never see "all the woods" along the entirety of a road.